# Android Saripaar Validator 2.0.3: How to check that one of the rules is valid

Tags: android, saripaar

Trying to use [Android Saripaar validator](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar) for case when only one of two rules is valid. For example:

```
@Empty // my custom rule
@Or
@Email(messageResId = R.string.useremail_wrong_pattern)
EditText etUserEmail;
```

In example above I need that etUserEmail can be empty (if user hasn't input anything in this field) or is valid email (if user has inputed email).
But example above don't work correctly. Even if user hasn't input anything, validator apply @Email rule to etUserEmail field.

Is there a way to implement this task? 
Maybe, I need create custom rule for @Or annotation? Can somebody give this rule example?

Comment: Hey, saripaar author here. I am very sorry. `@Or` hasn't been implemented yet. I made the mistake of leaking it into production. Will remove it in the next patch release. The next minor release will have the feature implemented. Right now, you can either use `@Optional` (at the moment please use Jitpack or build it from the source) or write a custom `@EmailOrEmpty` annotation.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment.